# How to change dropdown buttons of multiple drowdowns on click of another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I couldn't find any help on this but maybe someone has an idea, please.

Let's say I have two dropdowns A and B with two buttons each. On click of button A, dropdown content of A fades out and the buttons changes from nonactive to active. Another click on A, the content fades back in and the buttons goes from active to nonactive. Same goes for B of course.

Now; on click of A, content of A fades out, button is on active. Then on click of B, content of B fades out, button of B is active. Content of A fades back in (automatically) **BUT! button of A is still active :/**

I want the buttons to switch back to nonactive even if another button of another dropdown is clicked. It works fine so far if you click the same button but they stay active if you click another one.

See below my code.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```js
$('.panel .panel-heading').children('a.btn.btn-secondary').addClass('button_right collapsed');

$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.btn.button_right').click(function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var panel = $('.panel .panel-collapse');

        btn.removeClass('button_down button_right');

        // 
        if(btn.hasClass('collapsed')) {
            btn.addClass('button_down');
        } else {
            btn.addClass('button_right');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default m-b">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-default button_right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1344" href="#panel-1344-0" aria-expanded="false">

    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="panel-1344-0" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="panel-body">

      <div id="c1343" class="">


        <div class="ce-textpic ce-left ce-above">



          <div class="ce-bodytext">


            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
              no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
              justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
              erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

          </div>


        </div>


      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution meanwhile, for anyone who's interested. Thanks anyways to everyone who looked into my question.

I solved it via JS events given by bootstrap here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

```
$('.panel .panel-heading').children('a.btn.btn-secondary').addClass('button_right collapsed');

$('.panel.panel-default').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
var toggleButton = $(this).find('.panel-heading .btn');
toggleButton.toggleClass('button_right button_down');
});

$('.panel.panel-default').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
var toggleButton = $(this).find('.panel-heading .btn');
toggleButton.toggleClass('button_right button_down');
});
```